# How can I create sub domain for lambda serverless?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to create custom domain for lambda using this script. I get error regarding aws.

```
 plugins:
  - serverless-domain-manager

 custom:
  customDomain:
    domainName: transcoder.iflix-dev.com
    basePath: ''
    stage: ${self:provider.stage}
    createRoute53Record: true
```

> After that run sls create `sls create_domain -s development -v`
>
> Then deploy `sls deploy -s development -v`

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: Error: 'transcoder.esfeasdesfcs.com.' was not created in API Gateway.
BadRequestException: Trailing period should be omitted from domain name

Comment: Thank you. It would be very useful if you could add that to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Error: 'transcoder.esfeasdesfcs.com.' was not created in API Gateway.
>   BadRequestException: Trailing period should be omitted from domain
>   name

As described in the error message, you have an invalid domain name.

> transcoder.esfeasdesfcs.com.

is not a valid domain name. Try using

> transcoder.esfeasdesfcs.com

without the trailing period.

Answer (score 0):

For creating custom domain name for lambda serverless follow the given url
https://serverless.com/blog/serverless-api-gateway-domain/